# Docker Selenium - Tests pass in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I have a Docker Compose file with two Selenium Services:

```
  selenium-chrome:
    container_name: selenium-chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - teamcity-network

  selenium-firefox:
    container_name: selenium-firefox
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    ports:
      - "4448:4448"
    networks:
      - teamcity-network
```

I have another service set up with Protractor installed.

Here is my Protractor Configuration File:

```
exports.config = {
  onPrepare: function () {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TeamCityReporter());
  },
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  specs: [
    '/project/tests/**/*-spec.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {},

  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'shardTestFiles': true,
      'maxInstances': 2
    }
  ],

  'baseUrl': 'http://build-tool:8080',

  seleniumAddress: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'
};
```

This runs successfully, but if I change the browser name to firefox and the selenium address to my Firefox container - the tests fail.

1) includes coachcard directive should show coachcard types panel when checked

> Message:
>           Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://build-tool:8080/book/tests/directives/includes-coachcard/includes-coachcard-test.html
>   : retr
>       ies looking for angular exceeded
>         Stack:
>           Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://build-tool:8080/book/tests/directives/includes-coachcard/includes-coachcard-test.html
>   : retri
>       es looking for angular exceeded
>               at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:519:23
>               at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
>               at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
>               at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
>               at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
>               at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
>               at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
>           From: Task: Run it("should show coachcard types panel when checked") in control flow
>               at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
>           From asynchronous test:
>           Error
>               at Suite. (/project/tests/directives/includes-coachcard/includes-coachcard-test-spec.js:7:5)
>               at Object. (/project/tests/directives/includes-coachcard/includes-coachcard-test-spec.js:4:1)
>               at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>               at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>               at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>               at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

Does anybody have any idea why this would work for Chrome but not Firefox?

My test looks like this:

```
var TEST_PAGE = "/tests/directives/includes-coachcard/includes-coachcard-test.html";

describe("includes coachcard directive", function () {
    it("should show coachcard types panel when checked", function () {
        browser.get(TEST_PAGE);
        var panel = element(by.css('.test1 div.panel'));
        var checkbox = element(by.css('.test1 div.Checkbox-button'));

        expect(panel.isDisplayed()).not.toBeTruthy();
        checkbox.click();
        expect(panel.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Note - I can browse to the Test file over HTTP and it loads fine - no Angular errors.

Comment: is it because you opened port 4448 for firefox instead of 4444?

Comment: 4448 is just for me to access from my Host machine. It connects to the WebDriver on 4444 without complaining.

I should be doing 4448:4444 there though in order to connect on my host machine.

Comment: You can set browsers in multiCapabilities, delete line with capabilities it also can cuse a problem, try to create for firefox capabilite without 'shardTestFiles': true,
 'maxInstances': 2

Comment: Hi @Hikaryu

Thank you for your suggestion, I've modified the Protractor Configuration file along with Gunderson's suggestion but I'm getting the following error message now... (Image version of my paste to Gunderson)

http://tinypic.com/r/256fyux/9

Comment: @AntonRand add   allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
and paste error msg if appears

Comment: @Hikaryu,

I've added that parameter. I get the following error message in Protractor:

http://tinypic.com/r/23letx/9

Selenium output looks like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2qkhxmr/9

Comment: ah wait a second, what kind of Firefox you are using for ur e2e tests ? Try version 47 of Firefox for tests it might be a problem with this.

Comment: I was using the latest Docker Image which is version: 49.0.1.

I've just downgraded to https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox/tags   V2.53.1 which uses Firefox 47.0.1 but I got the same result - A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Any other ideas? Do you have much experience with Docker? I can try and set up a sandbox environment that has the same behaviour for you to see locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. The test I was running had a HTML import statement.

```
<link rel="import" href="thirdPartyScripts.html" />
```

This wasn't failing on my local Firefox because I must have set:

```
dom.webcomponents.enabled=true
```

In my preferences. I changed my code so that it doesn't use imports any more, but it is possible to set this preference on the Selenium Instance if required.

Chrome supports this feature but Firefox doesn't (by default) - http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a timing issue, see [this document](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) for reference to Protractor timeouts.

If it works on Chrome no problem, then the most likely issue would be fixed by the recommendations in the linked document: update your `getPageTimeout` in your config file.  The default time to wait for `angular` to be loaded in the app is 10 seconds.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and suggestion. I've tried that but I'm getting the following error message now:


F##teamcity[testFailed name='should allow click if property is true' message='Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Timed out waiting for async
script result after 11001ms|nBuild info: version: |'2.50.0|', revision: |'1070ace|', time: |'2016-01-27 18:43:24|'|nSystem info: host: |'1ea5f2cb0d86|
', ip: |'172.18.0.3|', os.name: |'Linux|', os.arch: |'amd64|', os.version: |'4.4.8-boot2docker|', java.version: |'1.8.0_45-internal|'|nDriver info: dr

Comment: Thats another timeout issue, also documented on the page I linked.  See the Waiting for Page Synchronization section, add `allScriptsTimeout: 60000` to your config, the default is 11 seconds.